# Button click, crashing

Tags: java, android

Every time I click my button, my application crash. I have tried to `Toast` the text and it still crashes. I have also commetted out my code and the button works. What's wrong here

```
final EditText Number1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
final EditText Number2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); //LINE 29
Button Add =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
final TextView Output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  int myNum1 = Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText().toString());
  int myNum2 = Integer.parseInt(Number2.getText().toString());
  Output.setText(Integer.toString(myNum1));
}
});
```

Error received.

```
05-16 17:50:35.912    1995-1995/com.example.addnumber.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.addnumber.app, PID: 1995
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
            at com.example.addnumber.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If it crashes it means that you got a stacktrace. Please post it with your question, don't let us guess what could the error be.

Comment: Updated ^ check now please.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` You're trying to parse an empty String. What does the fields contains when you press the button?

Comment: @ZouZou It contains a number that the user inputs.

Comment: Apparently not. What is the line 29 of MainActivity? I guess it is one of both line that are parsing the value in the editText.

Comment: @ZouZou Updated problem with line reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53852/discussion-between-zouzou-and-rynoh97)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty String made the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

So you should try with checking whether `text` value has proper value for`int`

```
if (!Number1.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    int myNum1 = Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText().toString());
```